# Caching ignores available memory argument

Tags: caching, dask

I'm processing a big dataset that does not fit into memory therefore caching is the only option.

Firstly, Dask's documentation is quite confusing when it comes to caching. There are 2 different sections about the topic suggesting similar  solutions.

1. [Opportunistic Caching](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/caching.html#opportunistic-caching), still flagged as an experimental feature introduced in version 0.6.2 (latest is 0.17.0)
2. ["How do I spill to disk?"](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/faq.html) in the FAQs, based on [Chest](https://github.com/blaze/chest)

Secondly, the caching to disk seems not working in my code. I try both approaches listed above. I instantiate a Cache/Chest object and register it globally, setting a synchronous or threaded or multiprocessing scheduler.
The caching mechanisms fails: it fills up the whole ram+swap memory, ignoring the `available_memory` parameter. Whenever I specify a cache path, I do not see the `.keys` file growing in terms of size.

How do I effectively spill to disk?

Using Dask v0.17.0, cachey v0.1.1, cloudpickle 0.5.2

Comment: https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/3172

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to spill to disk to day is just to use the newer dask.distributed scheduler (which works well on a single machine).  Try running the following:

```
from dask.distributed import Client
client = Client()
```

All computations should now use this scheduler by default (unless you explicitly override with `get=`).  This scheduler will handle spilling to disk by default.

Note that opportunistic caching as mentioned in your first link, is very different from spilling to disk to avoid memory issues.

Comment: solved. I didn't noticed the possibility to use that scheduler as I was used to either threaded or multiprocessing, thanks.

Comment: I also misinterpreted the opportunistic caching... I'm coding a simple ETL job that (1) reads and (2) writes a bunch of files. I though with the opp. caching the file read (1) could have been cached to disk while waiting to be written in step (2). Is that the case?

Comment: I wouldn't expect an ETL job to require any caching to disk.  Ideally the computation could read data, process it, and write it out without keeping much in memory.